# Use Regular expression with fileinput

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a variable stored in another file using regular expression. The code I have tried is:

```
r = re.compile(r"self\.uid\s*=\s*('\w{12})'")
for line in fileinput.input(['file.py'], inplace=True): 
    print line.replace(r.match(line), sys.argv[1]),
```

The format of the variable in the file is:

```
self.uid = '027FC8EBC2D1'
```

I am trying to pass in a parameter in this format and use regular expression to verify that the `sys.argv[1]` is correct format and to find the variable stored in this file and replace it with the new variable.

Can anyone help. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is it exactly that you need help with?  Does the code you've posted not work as expected, and if so, in what way does it not work?

Comment: @jchl -- The code does not find the string and just clear's the whole file. It's the regular expression that is the problem

Comment: Oh yes.  As others have said, re.sub is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` which will match the regular expression and do the substitution in one go:

```
r = re.compile(r"(self\.uid\s*=\s*)'\w{12}'")
for line in fileinput.input(['file.py'], inplace=True):
    print r.sub(r"\1'%s'" %sys.argv[1],line),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), not `str.replace()`:

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count])`
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of `pattern` in `string` by the replacement `repl`. If the pattern isn’t found, `string` is returned unchanged. `repl` can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. ... Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched by `group 6` in the pattern.
>
> ...
>
> In addition to character escapes and backreferences as described above, `\g<name>`  will use the substring matched by the group named name, as defined by the `(?P<name>...)`  syntax. `\g<number>`  uses the corresponding group number;

Quick test, using `\g<number>` for backreference:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"(self\.uid\s*=\s*)'\w{12}'")
>>> line = "self.uid = '027FC8EBC2D1'"
>>> newv = "AAAABBBBCCCC"
>>> r.sub(r"\g<1>'%s'" % newv, line)
"self.uid = 'AAAABBBBCCCC'"
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`str.replace(old, new[, count])`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)(old, new[, count]):

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring *old*  replaced by *new*. If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

`re.match` returns either `MatchObject` or (most likely in your case) `None`, neither is a string required by `str.replace`.

Comment: Ghost - I need to match the old string as it will change everytime someone enters in a new ID.